# opencv-python: is not a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I want to use the current array to be the output array of the blur operation made in the frame image and im getting this error:

```
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

I already checked and both are arrays of the same size and type, I dont understand why this is happening.

Part of the code:

```
previous = np.zeros((frameHeight,frameWidth,3),np.uint8) #blank image with 640x480 and 3 channels
difference = np.zeros((frameHeight,frameWidth,3),np.uint8)
current = np.zeros((frameHeight,frameWidth,3),np.uint8)

while True:
    # Capture a frame
    flag,frame = capture.read()
    cv2.flip(frame, flipCode=1)

    # Difference between frames
    cv2.blur(frame, current, (15,15))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to `cv2.blur`, as described [in the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#blur), are the following:

```
cv2.blur(src, ksize[, dst[, anchor[, borderType]]]) → dst
```

So, I think you meant

```
current= cv2.blur(frame, (15,15))
```

Comment: oh thanks!! I was used to use the older one the cv one instead of cv2, and then I do mistakes like this.. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: @user1832231 No problem. If there's nothing to add to the answer, make sure to mark it as accepted (there's a green checkbox next to it). Since you're just getting started here on SO, you may want to [read the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have open the image using **cv.CreateImage** instread of **cv2.imread**
You can use imwrite only if you have opened image using imread.